# Windows Server 2012 backup: the drive cannot find the sector requested

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012, windows-server-backup

I have recently activated my Windows Server Backup, and till now i am receiving in each full backup, one error in my C unit where i have the OS. And there is:

[image]
[image]

After doing some search I discover several people that have solved this problem shrinking the C unit in some megas or gigas (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/1219e165-f49e-4184-bb3d-9ed9daa6c14a/windows-server-2012-backup-the-drive-cannot-find-the-sector-requested?forum=windowsbackup).

But I have tried at least with some megas, and didnt work. After I made the shrinking I have logout from a remote connection and was unable to login again (access denied), I had to enter locally to reboot the system but it was working fine there. After that I gain remote access again and notice that there was no shrinking in that partition.

I have also run **chkdsk**, and there was no bad sectors:

[image]

This backup is being done to a NAS, and i dont think that the problem is in the destination, because in the last 6 backups, I only had problems with C unit. If was a problem from NAS I think that i would have problems with the other unit too, or in both at same time.

My next move will be try shrinking at least 1 giga, but i will have to wait for the end of the day because i have a few users using this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there was less space reserved for this partition then what is shown. So Windows Backup was unable to store that part of the partition. After trying with just several MegaBytes I decided to shrink 1024 MBs (1GB) and it have shrink but didnt show the entire GB that I have selected, it only remove 680 MB and not the entire GigaByte.

After doing this I have made a backup at once and it made it without problem.